# AJAX tabcontainer throwing exception when setting panel enabled=true

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a tabcontainer with eight panels in it. To make it more user-proof I had set 7 of the panels enabled=false until the user choose which item they wanted to edit/insert via a drop down. But when they choose an item and the dropdownlist does the postback I get the following error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method." I can choose continue and everything appears to work as normal but I obviously can't have the error.

I've googled and googled and googled some more and I can't find anything that fixes this. In the interim I have changed the code to have the panels Visible=false and that doesn't pop the error but I don't like being beat so if anyone has an idea on what's causing this and how to fix it I'd appreciate it.

EDIT: Additional information; the error only pops the first time through. I can reset the select and then make another selection and it doesn't error. So I'm guessing that something isn't right in the initial load.

EDIT Part Duex: The line in the ScriptResource that throws the error is:

```
if (!(cache instanceof Array)) throw Error.invalidOperation(Sys.Res.EvenHandlerInvalid);
```

So I'm guessing that means that if the panel has enabled="False" it isn't really loaded at page_load?

Comment: +1 cause I couldn't find the solution :D.  Will keep my eyes peeled.  If all else fails, use the previous version of the toolkit - I've read that some people are doing this.  Failing that, its simple to make a tab control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are not trying to access info or controls in another panel. I believe that the issue is that one panel is accessing or trying to access something in another panel.  Also you could try to have one Update Panel and put the seven DIV's in it and let the Dropdownlist show the selected DIV.

Comment: The only thing that happens when they do the selection is a stored procedure call that populates controls that are on the current panel and then enables the other panels. I took out the populate section so the code was only enabling the panels and it still pops the error.

Comment: ok then the visible will have to work for you or try to disable as the last thing in the pageload if its not a postback

Comment: Tried the disable at the end of Page_Load and that still didn't work. I'm probably going to be stuck with the Visible solution... but like I said I don't like losing :)